# tcpclient getstream - zero bytes read

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a tcpclient connection setup capturing a continuous http stream. For some reason  after the first few bytes are read, the stream does not get any data for a long time. Is there a problem with my code?

```
   Dim tclient As TcpClient = New TcpClient(url, "80")
   nstream = tclient.GetStream() 
  If nstream.CanRead Then
              defaultsize = 8000, BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
                Dim bufferread(defaultSize) As Byte
                Dim data As String
                mstring = New StringBuilder
                numbytesread = 0
                Dim timestamp As DateTime = DateTime.Now

                Do
                    numbytesread = nstream.Read(bufferread, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)

                    If numbytesread > 1 Then
                        timestamp = DateTime.Now
                        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferread, 0, numbytesread)
                        parsingUtilities.appendXMLtoFile(data)
                    End If
                    If DateTime.Now.Subtract(timestamp).TotalSeconds > 60 Then
            'timestamp shows no bytesread for more than 60 seconds, then reconnect
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                Loop While tclient.Connected
            End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you absolutely *should not* read character data in this way. You're assuming that your byte array always contains a whole number of characters. You should use a `StreamReader` instead, which is designed to handle this.

If you absolutely *must* read directly from the stream, use a single instance of `Decoder` which can handle these partial characters, buffering them for the next conversion.

Now, you're also *requiring* that `numbytesread > 1` - what if it's exactly 1? Why would you want to ignore that?

It's also not clear what your timestamp is for... isn't the stream going to block *indefinitely* until it gets some data? Or have you explicitly set it up with a read timeout?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was not sure how to capture the stream and took advice from another prgmmer..but I will look into either using streamreader or the decoder..Oh yes I remember now why I used the networkstream, I could not read from a tcpclient.getstream using a streamreader.What exactly do you mean by the stream blocking indefinitely and the read timeout.. I thought that if I am not getting anything in the stream for longer than a minute I need to reconnect.